# Edit specific bytes in a binary file - Java

Tags: java, inputstream, binaryfiles, outputstream, randomaccessfile

I want to know how can I do to edit specific bytes in a binary file  in Java.

Example, binaryfile before execution:

```
byteArray1[128].. Represents a array of 128 bytes.
byteArray2[128].. Other array of bytes
byteArray3[128]
byteArray4[128]
```

Just now, I take a new data to the byteArray3[128] in modifiedByteArray[128].
After execution:

```
byteArray1[128]
byteArray2[128]
modifiedByteArray3[128] .. The array in that position was modified.
byteArray4[128]
```

I have something like this code to append in the file:

```
//PASSFILE -> binary passfile path
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(PASSFILE, true);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutput);
long datos;

// cipherText 128 bytes
bufferedOutput.write(cipherText);
```

I have this data:
*modifiedData[128]*, the new cipherText in a specific position in the binary file.

*offsetPosition*, position where the array of the specific bytes starts.

Solutions about it? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at RandomAccessFile?

Comment: Do you just want a random access file instead of an output stream?

Comment: yes I think :X, I ddnt know about random access file. How it works?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted this , thanks all :

```
//PASSFILE -> binary file path
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(PASSFILE, "rw");

//Entrie = Array number to modify
int offset = (entrie * 128 );

raf.seek(offset);
// cipherText = 128 bytes of the new array for the speficic entrie
raf.write(cipherText);
raf.close();
```